# Can you push to a variable field using mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Suppose we have a simple userSchema like this:

```
{
    likes: Array[mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId],
    dislikes: Array[mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId]
}
```

I want to create a factory function (taking model from Like/Dislike and property from likes/dislikes) that after creating a like or dislike i.e.

```
const doc =  await Model.create...,
```

it pushes the new doc._id to the relevant field of the user object.

i.e. something like this:

```
    const updatedUser = await User.findByIdandUpdate(user._id,{
    $push: {`${property}`:doc._id}}
```

Unfortunately, I get errors for this type of syntax. Wondering if anyone has a solution to this. Obviously we can create separate functions outside the factory, or directly append to the relevant user field then call user.save(), but looking for something directly inline.

Tried various methods of variable inclusion into strings

Current solution I am using is

```
let doc = await Model.create(body);
user[type].push(doc._id);
const updatedUser = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, user);
```

Comment: `$push: { [property]: doc._id }`